# YUI editor toolbar button style

Tags: yui

I am working with the YUI editor and am stuck on a problem.
Specifically i want to change the style of the YUI toolbar forecolor button whenever someone selects a forecolor. For e.g. if one selects red forecolor then i want red background being applied to the forecolor button on the editor toolbar.

Button:-
`{ type: 'color', label: 'Font Color', value: 'forecolor' ,id:'forecolor',disabled:false}`

I am trying:-

```
editor.toolbar.on('colorPickerClicked', function (o2)
{
if (o2.button == 'forecolor') 
{
//alert(o2.button+'The selected color was: #'+o2.color);
YAHOO.util.Dom.setStyle('forecolor', 'background-color','#'+o2.color );      
}
}
```

But color changes are not reflected.
Is there a way to change the style (bg-color or button shadow etc) on selecting a color from forecolor button.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

yui editor forecolor button's id is not forecolor that's why its not working i guess .
Try using yui forecolor button class to identify it :

```
editor.toolbar.on('colorPickerClicked', function (o2)
{
   if (o2.button == 'forecolor') 
   {
       YAHOO.util.Dom.setStyle(YAHOO.util.Dom.getElementsByClassName(
              'yui-toolbar-forecolor'), 'background-color','#'+o2.color );      
   }
}
```

or you can use forcolor button id: `editor_toolbar_forecolor_menu`